# login at command prompt

Tags: login

I am trying to solve a low graphics mode problem. I have been able to get as far as the login prompt. The computer asks for my login. I don't know what my login is because I have never been asked for it. My password is a different matter. I enter my password for even the most mundane operations. What is meant by login? I have tried my password, my name with both upper and lower case, Administrator, in both upper and lower case, guest session in both upper and lower case, Admin in both upper and lower case. Any ideas? I am running Ubuntu 1204 LTS. Keep in mind that I am at the command prompt after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> -<kbd>F1</kbd> and not at the regular login screen which doesn't display because of the low graphics mode problem.

Comment: It's asking for your username. When you've been doing sudo stuff, your username was shown at the beginning of the command prompt, something like `username@host ~ $`.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're at something like this screen (it's says Fedora, but I couldn't find a TTY Session screenshot for Ubuntu... :) )

[image]

This prompt is waiting for your `username`.

After you enter your username and press `Enter`, you'll be prompted for your password:

```
password: _
```

Enter your password and press `Enter`. Volla!

P.S. Hopefully we can help you with your `Low Graphics Problem` later. :)